# How to know in "then" block what was true in "when"

Tags: drools

Below is some simple example of the dsl. Let's say in WHEN block the true is "city == "NY"", is there a way to know, in the "then" block, which condition is true?

```
rule "First Promotion"
    when
        m : Promotion( city == "NY" || products == "SCHERP_S" || assignedProduct == "SCHERP_XL" )
    then
**//Here I have to know what was true in WHEN block. For example city value is NY.**
end
```

thank you!

Comment: "Here I have to know..." This leaves it wide open in which way you want to have the knowledge which is available, prima facie, in the Promotion fact. Re-writing the conditions may not look good, but suppose you have a variable `term` set to 1, 2, 3: you still have to test `term==1` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

technically not since you used ||, but you could do multiple rules

```
rule "First Promotion_city"
    when
        m : Promotion( city == "NY")
    then
end

rule "First Promotion_products"
    when
        m : Promotion( products == "SCHERP_S")
    then
end

rule "First Promotion_assigned"
    when
        m : Promotion( assignedProduct == "SCHERP_XL")
    then
end
```

Comment: Thanks AwokeKnowing for an answer.
Business requirement says we have to use same rule with few conditions. This is why I added "||" into when. Your answer contains few rules, this is not good for us. Is there a way to set multiple "when" for same rule?
Or any another option? Please advise.
thanks.

Comment: Well, I see there is no way for multiple "when" in the same rule.

Answer (score 1):

Simply splitting the rule has the unpleasant side effect of requiring the multiplication of the condition (or using rule extension) and the multiplication of the consequences, with all disadvantages of code repetition.

A better solution is to use truth inference to create a suitable representation for a more to-the-point value.

Lets have a

```
class Reason {
    Promotion promo;
    String field;
    String value; 
    Public( Promotion promo, String field, String value ){...}
    //...
}
```

This can be used to register the reason for the disjunction using rules like this:

```
rule "First Promotion_city"
when
    m : Promotion( $city: city == "NY" || "LA" )
then
    insertLogical( new Reason( m, "city", $city ) );
end
```

I have added LA to show that multiple *values* can be handled with one rule.

The actual rule becomes

```
rule "First Promotion"
when
    m : Promotion(  )
    r: Reason( promo == m )
then
    //... access r for details
end
```

The disjunction may be true for more than one value, so you may have several Reason facts inserted. I can't advise on this since I don't know the "overall picture".

Clearly, the distinction on the RHS requires logic to decide what was true. But in the Q, there was no indication in which way one "has to know what was true". Accessing the original fact is, of course, the straightforward possibility. Having a value such as `r.getField` as a distinction right away, though, may be handy for selecting data from a map, etc. You get my drift.